50s movie with character screaming "Can radiation do this?"
Old (50s?) movie possibly in colour although I can't be sure, presumably it was out around the time of uncertainty regarding nuclear power.
There were a group of main characters who I recall appeared to be living in the countryside away from civilisation. Gradually characters began to die and all that is left behind is their clothes laid out as if the person had lain down flat on their back. 
Instead of a body though, all that was left was white dust. I clearly remember one of the main characters discovering one of these bodies and screaming 'Can radiation do this?!' over and over.
Any ideas? 

Is it this one?

Looks like it...I'll need to double check but it definitely is very similar. I've had a quick look and despite the premise being almost identical I don't think it's the same film. That one is more modern.

Well, I did check that scene just now and Peter Graves repeatedly asks "Could radiation do that?!" upon finding the powder. See here around 17:12. So I marked it as a duplicate, but if you're still convinced it isn't the right film, please let me know.

Has to be it, but my memory of it is different which just goes to show. Thanks, feel free to mark as a duplicate.

OP has confirmed a dupe of Post-apocalyptic movie from early 1970's - people turn into powder.
